# Why wont coalesce or is null work on results from a left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following sql, why wont coalesce work, or even is null? Does it have something to do because of the left join in there?

There are no rows for the subquery to return in this case. i. e `itemId = 'US1'` does not exist in table `amgb`.

I'm on MySql 5.5.25 on Windows 7 64.

```
SELECT  a.itemName,
  (SELECT coalesce(itemImageName,'default.jpg') // always null
    FROM amgb b
    WHERE a.userId = b.userId AND a.itemId = b.itemId
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS itemImageName
FROM amga a 
WHERE a.userId = 1 AND a.itemId = 'US1';

(SELECT if(itemImageName IS null,'default.jpg',itemImageName) // always null
```

Comment: Your second query appears to be using an alias from a prior query, so that may be a problem.

Comment: please read [THIS POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) I wrote on how to ask a proper question, it will help you get a better more accurate and faster answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's always `NULL` is because the `COALESCE` is *inside* of the subquery.  Instead move it outside like this:

```
SELECT  a.itemName,
  COALESCE((SELECT itemImageName 
    FROM amgb b
    WHERE a.userId = b.userId AND a.itemId = b.itemId
    LIMIT 1
  ), 'default.jpg') AS itemImageName
FROM amga a 
WHERE a.userId = 1 AND a.itemId = 'US1';
```